# Typescript Schema Validator Recommendation

Tags: typescript, validation, schema

I’m looking for a Typescript schema validator.

I want to my validation definition to also power my type definition, do form validation on the frontend, and reuse the logic on the backend.

Seems like ajv, joi, zod, and yup are options. Any recommendations here?

I researched all four but can’t tell which one to choose and it’s unclear if there are substantial tradeoffs between the libraries.